# extracting a substring from a string after and before a specified pattern in java

Tags: java

i want to extract a portion from a string which satisfies a particular pattern after and before the desired portion :

example :

```
String [] s1 = my name is ankit kapoor , my name is mayank gupta , my name is preeti singh ;
```

Here i only need the first name i.e ankit ,mayank , preeti 
i.e after is and before the occurrence of first space.

The code which i have use till now is

```
String [] final_reult = s1[i].substring((s1.indexof("is")+3) , (s1.lastindexof(" ")));
```

obviously im using loop i.e `for(int i=o;i<s1.length;i++)`

and output im getting is : ankit kapoor  // instead of ankit
                           mayank gupta  // instead of mayank
                           preeti singh  // instead of preeti

Please help !! 
i want to use this format only

Comment: Do you know about regex?

Comment: see StringUtils Class it has lot of useful function. explore and exploit the existing functions http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using a simple regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s1 = {"my name is ankit kapoor", "my name is mayank gupta", "my name is preeti singh"};
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("is ([a-zA-Z]+) ");
    for (final String string : s1) {
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ankit
mayank
preeti
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use `substring` to find the first name you would need to emulate what regex does, i.e. find the first pattern ("is ") and then walk along the `String` until you find a space.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s1 = {"my name is ankit kapoor", "my name is mayank gupta", "my name is preeti singh"};
    for (final String string : s1) {
        final int start = string.indexOf("is ") + 3;
        int end = start;
        for (final char c : string.substring(start).toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                break;
            }
            ++end;
        }
        System.out.println(string.substring(start, end));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ankit
mayank
preeti
```

Comment: cant i do using my method only i.e using indexof ?

Comment: yuppy...it works !! in case if i want anything after is and any word following it...im using this method :
String [] final_reult = s1[i].substring((s1.indexof("is")+3) , (s1.indexof(" ")));

but it is not working..

Comment: Isn't that the exact same method that you describe above that you say doesn't work? I don't understand what you want.

Comment: your method worked as i need...but what m trying to do is ...im parsing 10,000 strings like this and then i have to append this string with another string...and this is also working fine...but when im inserting into the database , only the last string from your method is printing...now m trying store this value in an array..lets see what can be done

Comment: String [] string - employee 180 name ankit is working these days,
employee 23 name chris is_a good character personality
for (i=o;i<text.length;i++){
id=string.substring(10,13);

or (final String string : s1) {
        final int start = string.indexOf("is ") + 3;
        int end = start;
        for (final char c : string.substring(start).toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                break;
            }
            ++end;
        }
        System.out.println(string.substring(start, end));

Comment: Please edit your answer or post a new question - that in incomprehensible.